# Django is_valid() returning false

Tags: javascript, python, django

I'm trying to validate a simple form with Django and it seems that it always returns false. I'm sending the value of the form via AJAX to the `views.py` and also printing the value in the Javascript and the `view.py` just to be sure it passed correctly.

The views file:

```
def change_alphabet(request):

cipher = CaesarCipher()
x = cipher.getListLetter()
y = cipher.getListLetter()
if request.is_ajax() and request.method == "GET":
    print("Inside CHANGE")
    formKey = caesarKey(request.GET or None)

    print("Valid or not: %r " % formKey.is_valid())
    integerKey = int(request.GET.get('the_key'))
    print(integerKey)


    if formKey.is_valid():
        print(request.GET.get('the_key'))
        integerKey = int(request.GET.get('the_key'))

        y = cipher.setCipherLetters(integerKey)

        context = { 'x': x,
                    'y': y,
                    'formKey': formKey,

        }

        return render(request, "content/alteredAlphabet.html", context)
    else:
        print(formKey.errors)
        context = { 'x': x,
                    'y': y,
                    'formKey': formKey,

        }

        return render(request, "content/alteredAlphabet.html", context)
```

The form:

```
class caesarKey(forms.Form):
key = forms.DecimalField(max_value = 26, min_value = 1, initial = 1, required = True, error_messages={'required' : 'Please input a valid key number!'}, widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class' : 'form-control', 'placeholder' : 'Key'}))
```

The Javascript:

```
  $("#keyButtonId").on({
click: function() {
  var variable = document.getElementById('id_key');
  console.log(variable.value)
  $.ajax({
    url: "/alteredAlphabet",
    type: "GET",
    data: {
      CSRF: 'csrf_token',
      the_key: $('#id_key').val()
    },

    success: function(json) {
      //  $('#id_key').val('0');
      // console.log(json);
      $('#letterSection').fadeOut('slow', function() {
        $('#letterSection').html(json);
        $('#letterSection').fadeIn(3000);
      });


      //document.getElementById('letterSection').value = json;
      console.log("FUNCTION CALLED!");
    }
  });
}
```

});

The error that is printed is:

```
<ul class="errorlist"><li>key<ul class="errorlist"><li>Please input a valid key number!</li></ul></li></ul>
```

UPDATE:

Template code for rendering the form:

```
<label for="id_key">
                Key:
              </label>
              <form onsubmit="return false;" method="GET" id="key-form">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-5">
                  {{ formKey.key }}
                </div>
                <button name="action" id="keyButtonId" class="btn btn-primary" value="key">Key</button>
              </form>
              {% if formKey.errors %}
                          <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                              <strong>{{ formKey.key.errors }}</strong>
                          </div>
              {% endif %}
```

Why is it always returning false? Am I missing an additional phase of bounding the data?

Comment: How are you rendering the form? What's the html?

Comment: By rendering, you mean the template? Or in the views using the render()

Comment: I mean template. Post your code for template.

Comment: Your Javascript sends a request with "the_key", but the form expects something named "key".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing your key data as `the_key` in the Ajax, but the form is expecting just `key`.